# Let G be connected simple graph, where all the vertices have even degree. Prove the following formula.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ an undirected graph.
Let $W(G)$ be the number of connected components in $G$.

Prove

$$\forall v\in V\ \ W(G-v) \leq \frac{\deg(v)}{2}$$
Where $W(G-v)$ is the number of connected component in $G$ after removinf from the vertex $v$ it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If a vertex $v$ is removed from a graph where every vertex has even degree, then there are precisely $d_G(v)$ odd-degree vertices.
2. However, by the Handshaking Lemma, every graph has to have an even number of odd-degree vertices. This implies that each component of $G \setminus \{v\}$ has to have an even number of the $d_G(v)$ odd-degree vertices.
3. Every component of $G \setminus \{v\}$ must have at least one of the $d_G(v)$ vertices that are adjacent to $v$ in $G$ [which now all have odd degree], and in turn, each vertex can be in only one component of $G \setminus \{v\}$.
4. So 2. and 3. together imply that each component of $G \setminus \{v\}$ must have at least two neighbours of $v$ [and that each neighbour of $G$ in $v$ is in one component of $G$].

Can you finish from here.

Comment: I am sorry, trying to figure out, what the next step is, but cant. Can you finish it please?

Comment: @JohnyBlaze do you agree with my 1,2,3 as I wrote above?

Comment: Meanwhile, I added 4. Let me know if this helps

Comment: Yeah, I can see it now. Thanks a lot!